# Why does a matplotlib axis object not have a set_scale method?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to set up a figure's Axis (note: Axis not Axes) directly rather than calls to Axes methods which require me to know up front if I'm setting up the x or y Axis.

I can set the scale for the x Axis for a matplotlib figure object using...

```
fig.get_axes()[0].set_xscale('log')
```

but I can't do it via something like...

```
fig.get_axes()[0].xaxis.set_scale('log')
```

because the Axis object (as opposed to the Axes object) doesn't have a set_scale method.  Though it does have a get_scale method (and seemingly many equivalents of set_[xy]???? methods, though I note no set_lim).

Is there a reason for this or is it just no one has thought of exposing it before?

(matplotlib 2.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

And then I found that the Axis object does have a method _set_scale presumably named to avoid a collision.

Noting the comment below that calling an underscored internal method is not a good idea the rather cludgy solution I came up with is...

```
def setup_log_axis(axis):
    if axis == axis.axes.xaxis:
        axis.axes.set_xscale('log')
    elif axis == axis.axes.yaxis:
        axis.axes.set_yscale('log')
....do more stuff
```

Comment: A single underscore at the start of a method name generally indicates it is for internal use only - see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

Comment: Noted.  I'm veering towards it being left out of the API by oversight.  The actual Scale object (something like <matplotlib.scale.LogScale at 0x600fc978>) seems to be an attribute of the Axis object not the Axes object so I assume invoking set_xscale on Axes just calls _set_scale on Axis but there is no public set_scale exposed.  There is also no set_lim.